# How to Skip Existing Data While Restoring mysqldump File?

Tags: mysql, restore, mysqldump, import, command-line

I use this query to import data using MySQL Dump (Command Prompt / Command Line)

```
mysql -u root -p database_name < database_name.sql
```

I want to import the large database (only new deltas) as of now I drop database and re-import but I want to import only new deltas.

Comment: *i want to import only new datas.* Create empty DB, copy "new datas" into it, then backup.

Answer (score 4):

I have four(4) suggestions:

## SUGGESTION #1 : Recreate dump with [`INSERT IGNORE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_insert-ignore)

Use [--insert-ignore](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_insert-ignore)

> Write INSERT IGNORE statements rather than INSERT statements.

What happens on reload ???

- New data gets inserted.
- Already existing primary keys are skipped

## SUGGESTION #2 : Change `INSERT` to `INSERT IGNORE` on reload

Instead of loading normally

```
mysql -u root -p database_name < database_name.sql
```

just pipe the dump into sed and reload like this:

```
cat database_name.sql|sed 's/^INSERT/INSERT IGNORE/'|mysql -u root -p database_name
```

## SUGGESTION #3 : Recreate dump with [`REPLACE INTO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_replace)

Use [--replace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_replace)

> Write REPLACE statements rather than INSERT statements.

What happens on reload ???

- New data gets inserted.
- Already existing primary keys will be deleted and re-inserted

## SUGGESTION #4 : Change `INSERT INTO` to `REPLACE INTO` on reload

Instead of loading normally

```
mysql -u root -p database_name < database_name.sql
```

just pipe the dump into sed and reload like this:

```
cat database_name.sql|sed 's/^INSERT INTO/REPLACE INTO/'|mysql -u root -p database_name
```

## SUMMARY

- Use suggestions 1 or 3 if you can recreate the dump
- Use suggestions 2 or 4 if you cannot recreate the dump

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Hey @manigopal if your deltas are just new rows, try suggestion 1 or 3. If your deltas are changed columns, try suggestion 2 or 4.

Comment: Heads Up : a REPLACE INTO performs a DELETE and an INSERT. So, more I/O will occur.

Comment: Good answer. Just one thing: cat is to conCATenate multiple files, you don't need it to pipe a single file to a command perfectly able to take a single file as input. `sed 's/^INSERT/INSERT IGNORE/' database_name.sql | mysql -u root -p database_name` will do the trick just fine

Comment: Hey @RolandoMySQLDBA 

SED & CAT queries are not working says 
'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,' the same for SED

Answer (score 1):

I would start by not trusting the dump.  So, I would load the data into a separate database (or at least separate table(s)).  Then I would run some SQL queries to verify that the deltas are what I expected -- whether that is "new" rows, no "dup" unique ids, etc.  If I find issues, then I would craft SQL to deal with the issues.  As Rolando suggests some INSERT/REPLACE [IGNORE] etc might be what is needed.

I might `DELETE` some of the 'new' rows, then `INSERT .. SELECT` to shovel the rest into the main table(s).  Or, equivalently (but possibly faster):  `INSERT .. SELECT .. WHERE ..` to shovel only the desired rows over.

Note also that `FOREIGN KEYs` may cause trouble.

Watch out for `PRIMARY KEYs` for any JOINs that are in your code, even if `FOREIGN KEYs` are not in place.

IODKU is usually better than `REPLACE`.  And it can be done via:

```
INSERT INTO t2 (...)
    SELECT ... FROM t1 WHERE ...
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... ;
```